# Non-existant model class properties, no errors, and ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, properties, error-handling, socialengine

We are using SocialEngine, produced using ZendFramework. This is not directly a question about SocialEngine, though it relates. This is not specifically a question about ZendFramework either; I imagine the lessons here are broadly applicable to most PhP MVC frameworks.

We have a problem whereby apparently under conditions of high load, some parts of the website stop showing up. For example, an entire widget's content will just fail to load without any apparent errors. The lack of errors to diagnose the problem is driving me crazy.

This is not at all a question about load or optimization.

I can reproduce the similar problem by calling a nonexistant class property from the ZendFramework view, model or controller, e.g.:

```
<?php echo $this->article->fubar; ?>
```

At that point the widget it is part of will fail to display without any apparent error. This is problematic when the widget itself is the main display part of the page.

I suspect these problems are ultimately caused by a class variable which has not been initialised but the codebase is too large to identify where without better error reporting. It could also be the result of a chained object failure, e.g. something like:

```
<?php $this->article->getCategory()->getTitle(); ?>
```

... could theoretically cause this behaviour if the getCategory() method returned null.

Furthermore, I believe the dearth of error reporting to be caused by 'magic' properties within the ZendFramework's data model, which allows for dynamic class properties such that if the data model has some field "blablabla", $this->article->blablabla is populated with the contents of that field. However, if the property to be accessed is not a database field this magical behaviour does not help very much, especially if it disables normal error reporting. This also explains why $this->article->fubar(); caused the widget to fail to load in the same manner.

How can I get accurate errors out of ZendFramework when faced with this behaviour?

Comment: When you say no errors, do you mean none appear on the page, or none in the error logs either? Can you repeat the problem in development, or only on your production server?

Comment: None at all that I can find either in the error log or in the screen. My guess is there's functionality which redirects them to the error log, then for... reasons... none actually appear. The problem occurs on both the production and dev servers simultaneously, then disappears on both as well which is why I think its ultimately related to load, and perhaps rate-limiting by an external service. Regardless: without errors, there's no way to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to catch the error by putting below code in controller's action or widget controller file?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

It can be possible that some of your article do not associated with any category or associated category has been deleted from category table, so $this->article()->getCategory() is coming null. It should not happen if category is required field for the article and category is exist in the category table. You can avoid the error by putting the !empty()/instanceof check for such code.